# Why do I get two Windows Boot Manager Prompts?

Tags: windows, boot

At the 1st prompt I get a choice of:

- WinXP
- another OS (now defunct)
- Win Recovery

If I select WinXP, I get a 2nd prompt with a choice of:

- WinXP
- Win Recovery

If I select WinXP at the 2nd prompt, then WinXP boots normally.

My question is: Where is the boot.ini for the 1st prompt? I can see the boot.ini for the 2nd prompt, on the root path of the booted WinXP. The booted drive has 2 partitions: WinXP (with the 2nd boot.ini), and a Windows swap partition. I can't see a boot.ini in the swap partition (using dir /a:h)

The boot.ini within XP is:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /NOEXECUTE=OPTIN /FASTDETECT
c:\CMDCONS\BOOTSECT.DAT="Microsoft Windows Recovery Console" /CMDCONS
```

This matches the 2nd prompt.

And I only just noticed that the 1st prompt is titled "Windows Boot Menu", but the 2nd prompt (matching boot.ini) has no title.

Is the 1st prompt coming from the MBR?

Comment: What is displayed in the OS list [within XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysdm_advancd_startrecover_default_os.mspx?mfr=true)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using EasyBCD to rebuild the MBR bootloader. I have this problem with my desktop, that loads first GRUB and then Windows bootloader with the same options, but I don't really care about that. EasyBCD might help.